# Play Framework Routes not working

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am just trying to follow along with the ZenTasks tutorial (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4) for the Play Framework. I can't seem to even get the Login page to work however.

I am running this project with the `play ~run` command. When navigating to `http://localhost:9000/login` the error is

```
Action not found For request 'GET /login'
These routes have been tried, in this order:
1 GET/controllers.Application.index()
2 GET/assets/$file<.+>controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)`
```

My routes file looks like

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# User athentication
GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.authenticate()
GET     /logout                     controllers.Application.logout()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and the Application.login, authenticate, and logout functions all compile properly. Am I missing something incredibly easy here, because I can't tell what is going wrong?

Comment: No, your `routes` file looks fine. Could you try restartig your Play application?

Comment: Have you started the right application? It seems that there are only 2 routes detected in your route file and those 2 routes are the default routes present in a newly generated project.

Comment: @Carsten I have restarted my application.

Comment: @i.am.michiel, I was thinking the same thing it. It is as if it is not detecting any changes. I definitely started the right application, this is my one and only Play application. I can get the index page to work fine, but none of the login or logout routes work. Any other possible suggestions?

Comment: Okay let's see...the file is called `routes` and lies in the `conf` directory? What happens if you deliberately introduce some syntax errors to the file and then reload (or restart the application)?

Comment: Try with play clean-all

Comment: @MaFo, thank you! `play clean-all` did it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the routes file wasn't compiled properly. probably, you should do a clean in the play console and try again

```
$ play clean-all
```

Comment: If you have activator, you can do activator clean

Answer (score 4):

@DiAlex

Just in case `play clean-all` doesn't work, you can try to

```
$ clean
```

then

```
$ compile
```

within the play console.

However, I think both of them do the same thing.

Comment: No, Compile does additional works in the comparison with clean command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using play framework via Activator you can simply do the follow steps:

1. sbt clean
2. activator run